# How to get a common mapping for multiple end points of the same REST API in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, rest, model-view-controller, mapping

Following MVC architecture, mapping with model is necessary for APIs. However, one API has 30+ different endpoints with different responses. How to get a common generic mapping that works for all? I can't find how to do this anywhere.

Comment: Make a generic api function to handle to the call. If possible try using Dio package for handling requests and jsonserializable for handling json model mapping

Comment: @CommonSense how to make a generic api function for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Call using http:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ApiClient {
  final String baseUrl;

  ApiClient(this.baseUrl);

  Future<dynamic> callApi(String endpoint, {Map<String, dynamic>? queryParams, Map<String, dynamic>? body, String? method}) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(baseUrl + endpoint);

    try {
      final response = await http
          .post(url, body: body, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
        // You can handle different responses based on the endpoint here
        if (endpoint == '/users') {
          return User.fromJson(responseBody);
        } else if (endpoint == '/posts') {
          return List<Post>.from(
              responseBody.map((data) => Post.fromJson(data)));
        } else {
          // Handle other endpoints and responses accordingly
        }
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to call API: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Failed to connect to the API: $e');
    }
  }
}

class User {
  // User model
}

class Post {
  // Post model
}
```

Same call using dio:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class ApiClient {
  final String baseUrl;
  final Dio _dio = Dio();

  ApiClient(this.baseUrl) {
    _dio.options.baseUrl = baseUrl;
  }

  Future<dynamic> callApi(String endpoint, {Map<String, dynamic>? queryParams, Map<String, dynamic>? body, String? method}) async {
    try {
      final response = await _dio.request(
        endpoint,
        queryParameters: queryParams,
        data: body,
        options: Options(method: method ?? 'POST', contentType: 'application/json'),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseBody = response.data;
        // You can handle different responses based on the endpoint here
        if (endpoint == '/users') {
          return User.fromJson(responseBody);
        } else if (endpoint == '/posts') {
          return List<Post>.from(responseBody.map((data) => Post.fromJson(data)));
        } else {
          // Handle other endpoints and responses accordingly
        }
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to call API: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Failed to connect to the API: $e');
    }
  }
}

class User {
  // User model
}

class Post {
  // Post model
}
```

Comment: Although this is just an example, feel free to tweak it as per your likings and need.

Comment: actually this is the exact problem. There are ~30 different endpoints of the API, how to put if else for each of them? It's quite impossible

Comment: Well, for that there isn't much of a go around except using for some kind of generator like json generator but for api. I haven't really used but would suggest swagger.